# Table not fixed on top after scroll down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually i'm using jquery to stop table after scroll down but this is not working properly. Sometime its vibrating and not fixed after scroll but sometime work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {  $('.reportAction').addClass('reportActionFixed');
            }
            else {
                $('.reportAction').removeClass('reportActionFixed');
            }
        })
});
```

```css
  .box{ height: 200px; }

.reportActionFixed{position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>

<table class="table reportAction">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


<img src="https://flyflytravel.com/images/destinacije/maldivi/840x500/maldivi840x500.jpg">
```

If i'm changing `scrollTop distance` then its working fine but not working while i give `scrolltop 200`. Anybody can fix it?

By the way i'm using simple latest jquery with CSS as given in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Chrome the snippet works fine every time

Comment: Please check in you own document, Actually if you will check in stack overflow then its work fine but after copy this code and paste into own document then its not working fine.

Comment: What's your goal ? If you need a fixed layout table at 200px from top, you can do it only with css. Ok I see, you want it to stay at 0 when scrolled to. Sry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `position: sticky` in the CSS class `reportActionFixed`. And if you don't need the white space above the table, then make `height: 0px` in CSS class `box` or remove it altogether.

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/15ht0z0m/10/)

Comment: I think you didn't check question properly because i want fixed this one (reportActionFixed) not relative.

If i'll position: relative then how it will be fixed after scroll?

Comment: So you want the table to appear on top of the image?

Comment: Actually when you will run this code in your PC instead of stackoverflow then you will understand automatically what problem going on.

Comment: I used jsfiddle. And I saw the problem that the table appears on top of the image in a weird way and it jitters sometimes. So I figured that you don't the table to appear on top of the image.

Comment: Only the jitter is the problem? Or you also don't want the table to appear on top of the image. Please be specific.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/15ht0z0m/8/), the table now comes on top of the image properly an no jitter occurs.

Comment: only jitter is problem

Comment: This fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/15ht0z0m/10/) don't have jitter. I hope this solves your problem. You can add `!important` in front of the `background-color: white` to get a solid white background with `color:black`

Comment: Thanks dear i got my answer, Actually problem was with position:fixed

I have to use position:sticky

Comment: I am gonna update the answer to reflect the desired result.